# Model A is not associated to Model B sequelize error

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have the following problem,
I have 2 Models: 
Client

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Client = sequelize.define('Client', {      
  first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  phone: DataTypes.STRING,
  mobile_phone: DataTypes.STRING,
  email: DataTypes.STRING,                             
});

//creating association Client with Gender
Client.associate = function (models) {
  Client.hasOne(models.Gender, {     
       //     
  });
};


return Client; }
```

and Gender:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const Gender = sequelize.define('Gender', {      
  name: DataTypes.STRING,                             
});

//creating association Gender with Employee
Gender.associate = function (models) {
  models.Gender.hasMany(models.Employee, {   
    //                         
  });
};

//creating association Gender with Client
Gender.associate = function (models) {
  models.Gender.belongsTo(models.Client, { 
    foreignKey: 'gender_id'                   
  });
};

return Gender; }
```

My ClientController:

```
const { Client, Gender } = require('../models');

class ClientController {

  // Apresenta todos os resgistros do determinado Model
  async index (req, res) {
      const clients = await Client.findAll({});

      return res.status(200).json({
          status: 'ok',
          clients
      });
  }

  // Apresenta os atributos setados de um resgistro específico
  async show (req, res) {
      const client = await Client.findAll({
          attributes: ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'mobile_phone', 'email'],
          where: {
              id: req.params.id
          },
          include: [{
              model: Gender,                 
              attributes: [],

          }],
      });

      return res.status(200).json({
          status: 'ok',
          client
      });
  }

  // Cria e salva um resgistro do Model especificado
  async store (req, res) {
      const client = await Client.create(req.body);

      return res.status(201).json({
          status: 'created',
          client
      });
  }

  // Edita e salva um resgistro do Model especificado
  async update (req, res) {
      const { first_name, last_name, phone, mobile_phone, email } = req.body;

      const client = await Client.update({
          first_name: first_name,
          last_name: last_name,
          phone: phone,
          mobile_phone: mobile_phone,
          email: email

      }, {
          where: {
              id: req.params.id
          }
      });

      return res.status(200).json({
          status: 'updated',
          client
      });
  }

  // Exclui um resgistro do Model especificado
  async destroy (req, res) {
      await Client.destroy({
          where: {
              id: req.params.id
          }
      });

      return res.status(204).json({
          status: 'removed'
      });
  }
}

module.exports = new ClientController()
```

But the following returns to me:

> node ./bin/www

api:server Listening on port 3000 +0ms
(node:16328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Gender is not associated to Client!
    at Function._getIncludedAssociation (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:715:13)
    at Function._validateIncludedElement (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:619:53)
    at options.include.options.include.map.include (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:516:37)
    at Array.map ()
    at Function._validateIncludedElements (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:511:39)
    at Promise.try.then.then (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:1726:14)
    at tryCatcher (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:547:31)
    at Promise._settlePromise (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:604:18)
    at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:649:10)
    at Promise._settlePromises (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:729:18)
    at _drainQueueStep (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:93:12)
    at _drainQueue (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:86:9)
    at Async._drainQueues (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:102:5)
    at Immediate.Async.drainQueues [as _onImmediate] (C:\SISTEMA-REACT-EXPRESS\api\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\async.js:15:14)
    at runCallback (timers.js:705:18)
    at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:676:5)
    at processImmediate (timers.js:658:5)
(node:16328) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:16328) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Obs: In n: m relationships with pivot Table, everything is normal, could someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're overwriting your first association with the second one:

```
//creating association Gender with Employee
Gender.associate = function (models) {
  models.Gender.hasMany(models.Employee, {   
    //                         
  });
};

//creating association Gender with Client
Gender.associate = function (models) {
  models.Gender.belongsTo(models.Client, { 
    foreignKey: 'gender_id'                   
  });
};
```

just combine them into a single one:

```
//creating Gender associations
Gender.associate = function (models) {
  models.Gender.hasMany(models.Employee, {   
  models.Gender.belongsTo(models.Client, { 
    foreignKey: 'gender_id'                   
  });
};
```